# XCode 4.2 (iOS 5) creating ipa file for ad hoc distribution -> "this kind of archive cannot be signed"

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios5

I'm trying to create an IPA file for my app for ad hoc distribution, but I got the following error "this kind of archive cannot be signed".

In my project I have 2 dependencies , CorePlot and ZXing; In target configuration->'Skip Install' to YES but in the dependency I leave it NO

In main project under target and project setting I set "Skip Install" to NO...

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean by "but in the dependency I leave it NO". Generally you want it to be NO for iOS components except the top level app.